# An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory

Tags: angular

a la hora de ejecutar ng serve en la carpeta correcta, me sale un error que me indica que lo estoy haciendo en una ruta inexistente

```
An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Home\Documents\Proshecto Integrador\Proshecto-Integrador\pi_jg\pi_jg'

See "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-joNlrf\angular-errors.log" for further details.

- Generating browser application bundles (phase: setup)...C:\Users\Home\Documents\Proshecto Integrador\Proshecto-Integrador\pi_jg\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\utils\helpers.js:177 throw new Error(Script file ${input} does not exist.);
Error: Script file pi_jg/node_modules/bootstrap-5.0.1-dist/js/bootstrap.js does not exist. at C:\Users\Home\Documents\Proshecto Integrador\Proshecto-Integrador\pi_jg\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\utils\helpers.js:177:23 at Array.reduce (<anonymous>) –
at globalScriptsByBundleName (C:\Users\Home\Documents\Proshecto Integrador\Proshecto-Integrador\pi_jg\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\utils\helpers.js:169:58) at getCommonConfig (C:\Users\Home\Documents\Proshecto Integrador\Proshecto-Integrador\pi_jg\node_modules\@angular-devkit\build-angular\src\webpack\configs\common.js:106:89) Node.js v18.0.0 –
```

a pesar de que el comando original sea

```
C:\Users\Home\Documents\Proshecto Integrador\Proshecto-Integrador\pi_jg>ng serve
```

¿Qué puedo hacer?

Comment: Hola! Bienvenidx a SOes. ¿QUé dice el log que angular te dice que revises? (angular-errors.log)

Comment: Por favor, aclara tu problema específico o proporciona detalles adicionales para resaltar exactamente lo que necesitas. Tal como está escrito, es difícil saber exactamente qué estás preguntando.

Comment: mil disculpas por responder tarde ;c 
respecto al (angular-errors.log) confieso que no sé como revisarlo jsksdjs perdón
------
Estoy haciendo un portfolio como proyecto, cuando abro el cmd  y me ubico en la ruta del proyecto (cd C:\Users\Home\Documents\Proshecto Integrador\Proshecto-Integrador\pi_jg)
-
luego escribo "ng serve" para poder ver el progreso a tiempo real 
y me termina saliendo el error que postié

Comment: An unhandled exception occurred: ENOENT: no such file or directory, lstat 'C:\Users\Home\Documents\Proshecto Integrador\Proshecto-Integrador\pi_jg\pi_jg'
See "C:\Users\Home\AppData\Local\Temp\ng-xPq5um\angular-errors.log" for further details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puede que tengas mal importado algun archivo dentro (EJ: bootstrap o algun estilo).
Sino podrias probar borrando el package-lock.json.

Comment: Tal y como está redactada, tu respuesta no es clara. Por favor, pulsa en [edit] para añadir detalles adicionales que ayuden a los demás a entender cómo esto responde a la pregunta formulada. Puedes encontrar más información sobre cómo escribir buenas respuestas [en el centro de ayuda](/help/how-to-answer).